# AgularJs avoid reloading ng-include when a value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive with its controller reloaded each time a request/route changes. This causes some page flickering since it has to fetch data from the server and this lag is noticeable. I would like to stop this without moving it outside the ng-view. Only use the ng-include and control it when the route changes.

My idea (maybe not the best solution, I welcome suggestions) will be to check if the value of 'notification_count' exists and and avoid reloading the content inside the SideCtrl. Let me know how you would go about this scenario.

```
 <section class="hbox stretch">
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <aside ng-include src="'views/partials/app_sidebar.html'" ng-controller="SideCtrl" class="bg-light lt b-r b-light aside-md  hidden-print hidden-xs" id="nav">
      </aside>
      <!-- /Sidebar -->

      <!-- Main content -->
      <section id="content" ng-controller="MetalsCtrl">
          <!-- Content -->
     </section>
     <!-- Main content -->




<!-- views/partials/app_sidebar.html -->
<div>{{notification_count}}</div>
```

Comment: can always cache the data so it doesn't have to be pulled from server again. `$http` even has a cache option, or can create your own cache

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have it set at $http service and it works well as I want. Trying to see how I can delete/clear the cache when the user logs out.

Comment: I have learned more here https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq

Comment: looks like just what you need

Comment: Yes, but I would like to keep the question open in-case someone has a better solutions. It works for me so far. Thanks again.

Comment: @charlietfl: Angular caches templates into `$templateCache` by default, so I don't see how using `$http` cache will help. I am surprised that Kiu says it works. Unless I have misunderstood and the lagging is not supposed to be due to fetching the template, but due to fetching the data to be shown in the template. In that cache, indeed using `$http`'s cache option is the solution.

Comment: @ExpertSystem my assumption was it was data related as OP mentioned

Comment: @ExpertSystem I wanted to fetch the data only once and avoid re-fetching when one one exists.I am reviewing the $templateCache option though and see how it works

Comment: @KiuFelix: As I mentioned above, `$templateCache` is just as any other cache (created using `$cacheFactory`), but used of storing templates. If the "data" you refer to are normal data (not templates) then you should use another cache (e.g. `$http`'s default cache or one you create yourself).